How to evaluate SIFT (scale invariant feature transform) for signature recognition problem
I am working on a signature authentication problem, using SIFT for the feature extraction. However my problem lies in evaluating the algorithm; for example I accept real signatures to show high numbers of matching points, and non-similar images to show smaller numbers of matching points, but in my case, both the real and fake signatures are showing a high number of matching points.  How am I supposed to evaluate this?
https://i.sstatic.net/gwK4w5HI.png
https://i.sstatic.net/Z4AEY5Sm.png
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# this code takes 2 transformed grayscale images and passed to the SIFT algorithm.
sift = cv2.SIFT_create()

keypoints1, descriptors1 = sift.detectAndCompute(transform_real_images[0], None)
keypoints2, descriptors2 = sift.detectAndCompute(transform_real_images[1], None)

bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_L2, crossCheck=True)
matches = bf.match(descriptors1, descriptors2)
matches = sorted(matches, key=lambda x: x.distance)


matched_image = cv2.drawMatches(transform_real_images[0], keypoints1, transform_real_images[1], keypoints2, matches[:20], None, flags=cv2.DrawMatchesFlags_NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS)


plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.imshow(matched_image)
plt.axis('off') 
plt.show()

